# Is it possible to retrofit rubber dome keyboard with mechanical switches?

Tags: keyboard

If yes, how complex would it be and would it be more simple than [building](http://cubiq.org/build-your-very-own-pc-keyboard) DIY mechanical keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCB in a rubber dome keyboard is printed with conductive material which is physically part of the switches. It does not have holes drilled in it which would accommodate mechanical switches. So the only part of the old keyboard you could use would be the case.